# Clipboard.getText() is not refreshing fast enough C#

Tags: c#, clipboard

I am using this code:

```
int X = Cursor.Position.X;
int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
DoMouseClick(X, Y);
SendKeys.Send("^a");
SendKeys.Send("^c");
clipText = Clipboard.GetText();

public void DoMouseClick(int x,int y) 
{
  int X = Cursor.Position.X; 
  int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, (uint)x , (uint)y, 0, 0); 
}
```

To copy text under the mouse, and saving it to "clipText".

The problem here is that, i don't get new text from clipboard, but i get text that i copied earlier. But if i call Clipboard.text() later in program, or if i press CRTL + P, i get the right text (the one i copied with code above).

Is there a way to refresh cliaboard, so i can get the latest text.

Comment: can you post DoMouseClick ?

Comment: public void DoMouseClick(int x,int y)
        {
            int X = Cursor.Position.X;
            int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, (uint)x , (uint)y, 0, 0);
        }

Comment: possible duplicate of [put in and get out of clipboard in a loop without delays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441188/put-in-and-get-out-of-clipboard-in-a-loop-without-delays)

Comment: How can the mouse be both down and up at the same time? And what context does the code run in.

Comment: i dont think that the problem is in the mouse click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why the SendKeys class has a [SendWait() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx).  It doesn't return until the target window has actually processed the keystrokes.

Comment: Thank you for you answer I am using this code: to check if clipboard has changed:            while (cliText.Equals(Clipboard.GetText()))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }